# How to prevent autofilll in Ract antd?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using Ant Design Forms in my React applpication. I want to prevent browser's credential manager from auto populating the password. Adding DOM attribute `autocomplete="off"` is not working for me. I also tried adding it in camelCase as pecified in [React Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html) but no luck!

```
<Form.Item label="New Password" name={["new"]}>
      <Input.Password autoComplete="off" placeholder="Please enter new password" />
</Form.Item>
```

All that I want to know is how do I prevent auto filling using Ant Design Forms in my React applpication.

Comment: Do your component Input supports the autoComplete flag?

Comment: As per this page https://ant.design/components/input/ no. It does not say anything about autoComplete flag.

Answer (score 2):

you need to put the property autoComplete="off" in the form.item, not in the input

```
<Form.Item 
   label="New Password" 
   autoComplete="off"
   name={["new"]}>
  <Input.Password  placeholder="Please enter new password" />
```

</Form.Item>

Edit:
Another option to prevent Chrome still autofill the user and email, its passing the autoComplete prop like this:

```
   <Input
      type="email"
      autoComplete="new-user"
      style={{ maxWidth:300}}
    />

    <Input.Password
      style={{ maxWidth: 300 }}
      autoComplete="new-password"
    />
```

This workaround really prevents chrome weird behavior

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this with an AntD password field component.

Using autoComplete="off" inside the Form.Item tag didn't solve it for me.

What solved it for me was putting it inside the Password element as thus:

`<Form.Item> <Password autoComplete="off"/> </Form.Item>`